# Is it possible to turn off code analysis for all JS files when using resharper 6.0?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper-6.0

Resharper uses up alot of memory (over 1GB of ram) when trying to run code analysis on the JS files in my solution which causes VS to become unresponsive.

Is it possible to turn off code analysis for all the JS files without having to tell Resharper to ignore each file individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in Resharper 6.0

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can here is a [link](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/06/preventing-items-from-being-analyzed-in-resharper/) explaining how to do it.

Comment: That requires you to specify each file or folder to ignore, I want to be able to specify to ignore any file with the extension .js

Comment: If you read the whole article you'll see that it is possible to insert a mask *.js, to ignore.

Comment: It says that you cannot turn off code analysis using a mask, you can use a mask to suppress messages but the files are still analysed. So I am guessing the answer to my question is that it is not possible.